# Which to use Auth::check() or Auth::user() - Laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

If I want to check whether the user is logged in within my Laravel 5.1 application I can either use

```
if (Auth::user()) {...}
```

or

```
if (Auth::check()) {...}
```

is there a reason to prefer one over the other when checking if a user is logged in?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Auth::check()` defers to `Auth::user()`. It's been that way since as long as I can remember.

In other words, `Auth::check()` calls `Auth::user()`, gets the result from it, and then checks to see if the user exists. The main difference is that it checks if the user is null for you so that you get a boolean value.

This is the check function:

```
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

As you can see, it calls the `user()` method, checks if it's null, and then returns a boolean value.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. :) But for me, it's just the intent behind the methods. I like writing `Auth::check()` if I want to "check" if a user is logged in. I like writing `Auth::guest()` to check if a user is a guest. It's a bit more readable to me than doing `!Auth::check()`. I like writing `Auth::user()` if I want to get the currently logged in user. You can probably get away with `Auth::user()` in this case because PHP is a dynamic language, but I think it helps to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: As stated in docs you even can put `@unless (Auth::check())
    You are not signed in.
@endunless` directive surrounded expression on a desired blade page

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to check if the user is logged in, `Auth::check()` is more correct.

`Auth::user()` will make a database call (and be slightly heavier) than `Auth::check()`, which should simply check the session.

Comment: This answer should be combined with the green check answer as well imho.

Answer (score 5):

I recomend you to define `$user = auth()->user();` If you want to check if user is authenticated or not **and** user model properties like email, name, ... in your code.

Because `auth()->user()` and `auth()->check()` both will query to database. If you want more speed in your apps, define `$user = auth()->user();` then you can us it in your codes and also you can check if user is authenticated via `$user == null;`.

Don't use `auth()->check()` and `auth()->user()` both in one function or one block of code to have low queries to database and more speed apps! ; )

Answer (score 1):

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->email
```

try this it worked for me.